# In my test script it have to click on one button but it is clicking other button in selenium webdriver with Cucumber

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I have a pay button in my application in below of my page which is directly visible and no scrolling required.

But when it is executing it is clicking the other button which is not all having any same locator data with pay button.. So i tried using id, xpath of that pay button and I tried to highlight the pay button to know which one is actually pointing.

Everything is pointing to pay button only but at click time it is selecting other button.

Comment: Please (minimal amount of) code to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please do click using javaScript executor to click the pay button and check whether the Id or xpath duplicate